# Decent quality portable bluetooth speakers.

Tags: bluetooth, speakers

I would like some speakers primarily for use in my bedroom.

I would like to be able to play sound through both my laptop and my phone.

Loudness is not of particular importance, but I would like decent sound  quality (For reference I own a pair of Rokit RP6 G2 monitor speakers, which I love the quality of), including presence of bass.

Portability is a plus - I don't want the speakers to take up too much room, and being able to play from battery would be a plus, but not essential.

I'm otherwise not wanting to break the bank - I'm looking for good audio quality, without spending too much money.

Comment: What country are you in?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend the [Juice Bar](http://juice.co.uk/pages/product/juice-bar) portable speakers.

I've had one of these for about half a year, and I've been very happy with the quality of both the build and the audio - and that's coming from a professional sound engineer! They've also got great range - I managed 20m indoors, through brick walls, and around 35-40m outdoors. They're available in a range of colours.

Current price in the UK is just under £40, which is US$52 as I write this. Not the cheapest, but they're certainly worth the money.

Answer (score 3):

I use a Jabra Speak 510, very good sound quality, can do much more than just speaker but a little expensive (about 100€)

Edit for details : battery YES, autonomy more thant 10 hours, USB and jack 3.5mm port
Size : round, diameter about 10cm for 2.5cm height
Link : http://www.jabra.co.uk/business/speakerphones/jabra-speak-series/jabra-speak-510

Comment: Can you add more detail to your answer please? How portable is it? Does it have a battery? How big is the unit? Can we have a link to the product?